# Wordpress Plugin - file_get_contents doesn't load contents

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pdf-generation

I think this happened after the wordpress update of 4.3

so here is the issue in a plugin there is one line

```
$html = file_get_contents($link . (strpos($link, '?') === false ? '?' : '&') . 'pdf-template');
```

It no longer loads any content, and samething happens when replaced with any internal links.

`echo file_get_contents('http://example.com');`

But when replaced with external links this function displays the content.

Anyone know what is going on? also tried to use `wp_remote_fopen` which made everything work, but all the images the pdf maker creates cannot be found, even if it is the correct absolute path.

Comment: What do you mean by internal vs. external? Are you referring to internal relative paths such as /somefile.php vs. http://example.com/somefile.php, and if so, why can't you just prefix the link with the name of your site?

Comment: internal are links of my own web domain and external can be google yahoo or any other sites

Comment: Edit: never mind, read wrong. What's the error you're getting, is file_get_contents returning false or throwing any errors? Try turning on WB_DEBUG to true on the constants file

Comment: returns no value, but when you type the url it is trying to get it returns the right display contents.

Comment: Sorry, so file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/file.php'); returns no value for any page on your domain, but it returns a value for any domain other than your domain and it returns the value you want?

Comment: Also Wordpress automatically drops any querying on your own domain that it doesn't recognize. And you seem to be concatenating additional parameters to the end of your domain. You can read here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-pass-value-in-wordpress-url